# What is the background of the expression "쩐다!"?

Tags: etymology, slang

Today I learned about the expression "쩐다!" as a more colorful way of expressing "좋다!"

What exactly is the background of this word and how is it different from saying "좋다!"?

Comment: By the way, 쩐다 is 급식체. 급식체 is the bad made up words by kids and their background is usually swearing... so you should not use words like쩐다 if th like Korean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's from dialect word "쩔다" which means "salt down".

And It can be use both side of "The best" or "The worst" like "awesome".

ex) 니 얼굴 쩐다. -> Your face looks awesome.(Bad or Good)

Comment: **“Your face looks sick!”**

Answer (score 2):

1) 절이다 : preserve fish in salt 생선을 소금에 절이다.

Clothes with a lot of sweat has a terrible smell. 땀에 절은 옷은
냄새가 안좋다.

2) 찌들다 : be worn with domestic cares. 살림에 찌들다

3) a regional dialect : Why do you have a tired face ? 너 왜 절었니
?

4) 쩐다 : When 3) of negative meaning is popular, 쩐다 means **shock** (In English, it is corresponded to oh, Wow, my god, etc).
Here it can be both a positive and a negative.

Wow, you are very ugly 와, 너 쩐다

Wow, you are very pretty 와, 너 쩐다

@That is, we must guess meaning of 쩐다 through situation

The movie titanic is totally masterpiece 타이타닉 완전 쩔어